# UIView animating subviews conditionally using custom property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I have two subviews - scrollviews whose content offset is set conditionally using one (CGFloat)**property** on the superview. I would like to animate the change to this **property** so that the animation is fluid.
The problem I have is that when I use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:...
              ...
              animations:^{
 self.property = x;
}
```

the animation does happen but the two scrollviews are animated independently and don't follow the rules of the **property** setting triggered in the setter (recursive calls setting offset on one scroll view and another, etc...).

I tried to use custom CALayer, with a property' linked to the custom view's **property** and animate this property' using CoreAnimation, where the animating keyPath was this property'. I overrode

```
+(BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *) key
```

As a result, nothing was animated.
Is there any way how to animate my **property** so that the result is one fluid animation?

EDIT: I know this could be done by using timer and doing some maths (for the effect of timer function of animation such as 'ease out'), but I guessed there might be a more elegant solution and more reusable (using different timer functions, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a CADisplayLink in the end to update the property value continuously and computed the update-difference using an easing function for the ease-out effect.

Answer (score 0):

What type or class is your property? It is unlikely you can increment any basic type using animate with duration, you may be better using a for loop and incrementing it yourself.